# Add a vertical line on MouseDown event

Tags: wpf, mvvm, line, oxyplot

This seems very simple and straightforward, but I can't really get it to work.

I have a Line chart where I fill the data through binding to a List.

I want to create a command that **adds a vertical line when the user presses the left mouse button**. I would like to be able to do it in the ViewModel, but code-behind would work aswell.

Furthermore, I would like to set a limit of one vertical line per graph. So when the user clicks and there's already a vertical line, it should remove the old one and add the new one at the new position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to add event handlers:

```
YourControl.Click += (sender, args) =>
{
    // Your code here
};
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @lucas.mdo can you please mark this as answer if this is correct

Answer (score 0):

I came here to answer my own question, and found Konstantin's answer to have the same idea as my approach. I'll leave mine just to show the whole code.

```
    model.MouseDown += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == OxyMouseButton.Left)
        {
            //Remove any existing Marker
            while (plotView.Model.Series.Where(x => x.Title == "Marker Line").Count() > 0)
            {
                var oldmarker = plotView.Model.Series.Where(x => x.Title == "Marker Line").FirstOrDefault();
                plotView.Model.Series.Remove(oldmarker);
            }

            // Add a point to the line series.
            marker.Points.Add(marker.InverseTransform(new ScreenPoint(e.Position.X, model.DefaultYAxis.ScreenMin.Y)));
            marker.Points.Add(marker.InverseTransform(new ScreenPoint(e.Position.X, model.DefaultYAxis.ScreenMax.Y)));

            //Add the marker (vertical line)
            plotView.Model.Series.Add(marker);
            model.InvalidatePlot(false);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        e.Handled = false;
    };
```

I still have some fixes to do (like autoscaling the marker), but this is as close as I've got so far.